# UICollectionView Scroll CrossDissolve animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a paginate UICollectionView with full page UICollectionViewCell. 
I need sometime to scroll to item **without** the slide animation but with a fade in / fade out animation.

I have try this :

```
[UIView transitionWithView: self.mCollectionView
                      duration: 0.35f
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations: ^(void) {
                        [self.mCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[array objectAtIndex:random] integerValue]
                                                                                         inSection:0]
                                                     atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone
                                                             animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    }];
```

But the slide animation is still present.
Have you any idea to remove it, or maybe there is an other way to do this.

Thanks.